# Multi-column sort with VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I'm using VBA to sort columns in Excel 2003. I need to sort by column 5 ascending, then column 3 using a custom order, then by column 4 ascending. I'm having difficulty getting the sort to work and I don't totally understand how OrderCustom applies.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated :) My code is below.

```
With wsData
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim n As Long
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("LOW", "MEDIUM OR HIGH", "HIGH ONLY")
    n = Application.GetCustomListNum(Array("LOW", "MEDIUM OR HIGH", "HIGH ONLY")) + 1

    Dim strSortOrder As String
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)).Sort _
        Key1:=.Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=.Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)), Order2:=xlDescending, _
        Key3:=.Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)), Order3:=xlDescending, _
        OrderCustom:=n, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try splitting your sort into 3 seperate steps, with only the second one using your custom sort order, i.e.

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)).Sort _
        Key1:=.Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes

.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)).Sort _
        Key1:=.Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        OrderCustom:=n, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes

.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)).Sort _
        Key1:=.Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(lastrow, lastCol)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes
```

Note that I have reversed the order in which these sorts are performed in comparison with how they are declared in the original statement.